# Banco de dados wordpress x memória

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, wordpress, cpanel, whm

Tenho um site de notícias feito em wordpress, hospedado em um VPS na godaddy, e devido à grande quantidade de acessos, estou tendo problemas com a hospedagem, o banco de dados cai quando temos muitos acessos e as matérias ficam inacessíveis, dando o seguinte erro:

> **"Error establishing a database connection"**

e quando vou acessar o /wp-admin recebo o mesmo erro.

Tentei acessar o phpmyadmin pelo Cpanel, mas recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> O servidor MySQL está atualmente offline.
>  Error while
>   connecting to MySQL: (XID qh3rc5) Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) Error while connecting
>   to MySQL: (XID qh3rc5) Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) at
>   /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Mysql.pm line 181.

Sim, pelo q entendi o banco de dados caiu. Minha pergunta é:
Existem configurações que eu possa fazer dentro do WHM ou do CPanel que possam me ajudar a 'liberar' mais memória para o php?

Atualmente estou usando o [sitelock](https://br.godaddy.com/pro/sitelock) junto com uma CDN do próprio sitelock.

Seguem as configurações do servidor:

```
Linux, 3GB RAM, largura de banda de 3 TB/mês e 90gb de disco.
Total processors: 24
Intel Xeon CPU ES-2630L V2 2.40GHz
```

Já vi ele dando pico de RAM quando temos 280 acessos simultãneos, mas não foi este caso. 
A largura de banda que usamos não passa de 600GB por mês.
E o disco não usamos nem 10GB

Gostaria muito de ver possíveis alternativas antes de ter que contratar um dedicado. E se caso só tenha esta opção, qual hospedagem vocês me recomendariam para o dedicado?

Comment: Esse erro não parece que seja por "excesso" de uso do banco de dados. Normalmente quando existe uma 'sobrecarga' é apresentado que atingiu o `max_connections` ou que `max_user_connections` foi atingido... Nesses casos o MySQL está ali, ativo, porém recusa conexões. No seu caso o banco de dados APARENTEMENTE é encerrado por algum motivo. O problema por mim pode ser outro. Alguma tabela corrompida, danificada ou coisa do gênero, para isso veja o LOG do MySQL, nele contem o motivo que ele foi encerrado.. Monitore no `TOP` o  tempo de funcionamento e quão frequente ele reinicia.

Comment: Estou tentanto encontrar o arquivo de LOG, acabei de reiniciar o servidor e agora está dando pico de RAM, 99%